# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application Not Receiving Post Data From iOS?

Tags: php, ios, cocoa-touch, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

this one has me scratching my head. I'm developing an iOS application that communicates back and forth with a server. I've been developing using my local ip and writing server side code on my laptop for the sake of testing, using XAMPP and PHP.

I'm sending POST data from the iOS application using the following code.

```
- (void)doAsyncPostWithCallback:(NSString *)method arguments:(NSDictionary *)arguments post:(NSDictionary *)post target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    NSString *urlRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", kApiUrl, method];

    if ([MochiCart session].apiKey) {
        urlRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/apiKey/%@", urlRequestString, [MochiCart session].apiKey];
    }

    for (id key in arguments) {
        NSString *argument = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@", key, [arguments objectForKey:key]];
        urlRequestString = [urlRequestString stringByAppendingString:argument];
    }

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlRequestString]];

    if ([post count] > 0) {
        NSString *postString = nil;
        for (id key in post) {
            NSString *keyValue = [post objectForKey:key];
            postString = (postString) ? [postString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", key, keyValue]]: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, keyValue];
        }

        NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    }

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    id cTarget = (target) ? target : [NSNull null];
    id cAction = (action) ? NSStringFromSelector(action) : [NSNull null];

    [self.connectionInfos setObject:@{@"target" : cTarget, @"action" : cAction, @"responseData" : [[NSMutableData alloc] init]} forKey:[connection description]];
}
```

This works wonderfully when I'm sending POST data to the server on my laptop, however - when sending it to the production server running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, the response is acting like it's not receiving any POST data at all. The request goes through fine, but there's no POST data being received on the server end for some reason?

My first though was maybe AWS and send POST data via mobile don't work together (Although it shouldn't matter), and of course - using iOS safari to log into the web portion of my AWS Application works fine...

So, again.. Does anyone have any clue as to why AWS is not receiving POST data using my code above to send it, but my local server receives it fine?

Comment: What is the HTTP response tou your POST request?

Comment: The problem was not having www in the URL.